# Using like operation in SOLR

Tags: java, solr

I am using SOLR search engine.

Few days back i came up with requirement for performing like operation on a given column.

Eg:

```
Column name: Name

Content: Stackoverflow is good.
```

Query is

```
Name:("*overflow is*")
```

This query should give me specific
**"Stackoverflow is good."** as a result

This input parameter should be considered as a whole input. It should not be considered as a Free text search. It should work as 'like' operation in SQL.

For that iam using this configuration.

```
<fieldtype class="solr.TextField" name="string_wildcards" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldtype>
```

This query is not giving me result as expected from 'like' operation.

Eg:  Name:("*overflow is*")

would search as FREE TEXT and not like 'LIKE' operator.

It gives me result as

1. What is overflow.
2. My name is ABC
3. What is overflow
4. Stackoverflow is good.

My expected result is only point 4, where as above configuration gives me all 4 results, which is wrong.

Kindly help me with correct configuration for my requirement.

Comment: :) sorry for that. I would like to know, the correct configuration for my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The point is, that you split/tokenize your input with the StandardTokenizerFactory.
In this case you search for `*overflow` and `is*`.

But:  the wildcard character on the left side, like

> *overflow

is not supported by solr by default.
In that case you have to index the field (column) "Name" twice.

That means: add an file name from type string_wildcards, as you wrote an add an 2nd field - lets call it `eman` (reversed: name)  from type left_wildcards_string. At this fieldtype-definition you add the [solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory)

Finally your span your search over both fields.

Comment: yes i can remove * from query. but then it does not give me results. should i change or add any tokenizer class ?

Comment: please take a look at my changed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Default boolean parameter between keywords is OR, that is why you get all 4 results.